# Rails test if a value fits with the type of a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to check if a value fits with the type of a column, something like this

```
  1.is_a? Product.columns_hash["id"].type
"a".is_a? Product.columns_hash["id"].type
```

But `Product.columns_hash["id"].type` returns `:integer` not `Integer` class.

Comment: Why are you *type checking* ? Anyway *ugly* way - `1.is_a? Module.const_get(Product.columns_hash["id"].type)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you need to do this but this should work

```
1.is_a? Product.columns_hash["id"].type.to_s.classify.constantize
#=> true
"a".is_a? Product.columns_hash["id"].type.to_s.classify.constantize
#=> false
```

Can you specify a purpose for this as it might be something more easily handled through other conventions.

You could patch this into `Symbol` if you wanted like so

```
class Symbol
  def to_constant
    self.to_s.classify.constantize
  end
end
```

Then call

```
1.is_a? Product.columns_hash["id"].type.to_constant
```

just be careful with altering Base Classes. Also technically in > 2.0 you could do this

```
module ColumnChecker
  refine Symbol do 
    def to_constant
      self.to_s.classify.constantize
    end
  end
end 

class YourFilterClass
  using ColumnChecker

  1.is_a? Product.columns_hash["id"].type.to_constant
end
```

Which technically is a safer way to do this as of Ruby 2.0

Comment: on a filter... i need to check if the query value matches with the columns types. I'm using this solution to make filters http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2014/02/17/search-and-filter-rails-models-without-bloating-your-controller/

Comment: @mariowise okay but `Rails` handles conversions pretty well especially Integers `Product.find(1)` will return the same as `Product.find("1")`. Even `Product.find("1ABC")` will work but `Product.find("ABC1")` will return a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`

Comment: Yep, but the filters uses the `scope` definition (i'm not very happy on that). So I'm currently passing the value directly to the scope lambda.. which writes in the query as is.. 
`scope :barcode, -> (barcode) { where("barcode = ?", "#{barcode}") }`
Then as :barcode is a Integer, I must check if the value on the search query is a Integer
Your solution works ver well ;)